# Why is tin loaf bread not usually scored like other forms of bread?

Tags: bread

Here is what I already understand, Bread needs to be scored so that there a clear path out for the pockets of gas that will expand when heated up, if there is no scoring the gases will burst from a seemingly random place which could miss up the way it looks, why doesn't that happen with recipes like this

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=luqevMbco8Y

or this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VrUdtzXquWk

I think I can see where the gases burst on the side but why don't they score it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at your videos again, you will notice that the loaves did rise a lot during the second rise in the tin. They were fully proofed and therefore the oven spring (the expansion in the oven) is minimal. Plus, they are both baking at relatively low temperatures.

Bread can be baked at different stages of proofing, you may have heard of the poke test - essentially indenting your loaf and see how it springs back - to determine when a loaf is fully proofed. Catching a full proof is a tricky thing because on the other side of “full” lies “over-proved”, which for free-form loaves means essentially a collapsed bread instead of oven spring. So for many free form loaves, bakers will bake at a “well-risen, but not yet fully proofed” stage and slash to allow for the greater expansion of these loaves. Slashing a fully or even slightly overproofed loaf is a bad idea, it will likely collapse the bread. Steaming also helps to keep the crust pliable for a bit longer.

A bread in a tin can also be scored, but you can go for a full proof with less risk: If you overproofed slightly, the tin will still hold the bread together where a free-form loaf flows outward. If you look at your videos, you will notice that the bread rises a lot before going into the oven and only a bit during baking.

The type of bread is also a factor. Your videos show a classic white sandwich loaf. This kind of bread has a rather fine crumb structure with lots of small holes, achieved by kneading after the second rise. This type expands very evenly, which means less uncontrolled bursting. And finally, both bakers use rather low temperatures (180-200 C is low in bread baking terms), which means the top crust won’t set as quickly as at hotter temperatures and the oven spring is also a bit slower and more regular.

Answer (score 1):

Scoring a loaf allows it to expand in a controlled manner during cooking, without the surface ripping after it's gelatinized and dried. Loaves cooked in a loaf pan are less prone to ripping than free-form loaves, because much of their surface area is enclosed by the pan and does not dry during cooking.

Comment: While the part about scoring for controlled expansion is correct, your conclusion is not: The sides of the loaf are restricted by the tin and the top hardens just like free-form loaves. I have seen (and made <*cough*>) enough breads that had too much oven spring and burst at the seam between tin and top.